# How do I login to a website programmatically when it crosses over from HTTPS to HTTP?

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, cookies

An example site is: http://www.dotmed.com. The login page is at: https://secure.dotmed.com/login.html (Secured by SSL HTTPS). When you authenticate, you get redirected to: http://www.dotmed.com/index.html (Not secured by SSL).

I am using code from previous posts, but the "session" doesn't seem to persist across requests. Maybe this has something to do with the cookies being set in one domain and trying to access a page in another domain? Not sure.

```
    public static void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
            client.BaseAddress = "https://secure.dotmed.com/";

            // Do a simple GET on the Login page first (It sets cookies)
            string source = client.DownloadString("login.html");

            // Attempt a POST to the Login page
            NameValueCollection loginData = new NameValueCollection();
            loginData.Add("refer", "");
            loginData.Add("backfromssl", "1");
            loginData.Add("user", "*****************");
            loginData.Add("pass", "*********");           
            byte[] ret = client.UploadValues(LOGIN_PAGE, "POST", loginData);
            string pageSource = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ret);       // I can see the user is logged in successfully here

            // Now you are logged in and can request pages
            client.BaseAddress = "http://www.dotmed.com";            // ???????????????
            string htmlSource = client.DownloadString("index.html"); // ???????????????
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

My CookieAwareWebClient class is pulled directly from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907201/787794

When I try the client.DownloadString() method with the question marks next to it, it returns a page where the user is not logged in. How can I make the authentication stick across requests?

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that (1) your client is handling cookies correctly, (2) you are logging in correctly, and (3) the `http://www.dotmed.com` server is working as expected, then the problem might be the cookie set by `https://secure.dotmed.com`:

1. To be usable across subdomains, the cookie domain must be `Domain=.dotmed.com`
2. Since it was set by HTTPS, the cookie MUST NOT set the `Secure` flag if it is to be usable on a non-HTTPS request.