# C# Login to website with Token authentication, only works sometimes

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have been looking around and tried different options but decided to use this one: [Logging into website via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906619/logging-into-website-via-c-sharp)

```
 string username = "username";
        string password = "password";

        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient(cookieJar);

        // the website sets some cookie that is needed for login, and as well the 'authenticity_token' is always different
        string response = client.DownloadString("https://gitlab.mydomain.com/users/auth/ldapmain/callback");

        // parse the 'authenticity_token' and cookie is auto handled by the cookieContainer
        string token = Regex.Match(response, "authenticity_token.+?value=\"(.+?)\"").Groups[1].Value;
        string postData =
            string.Format("utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token={0}&username={1}&password={2}", token, username, password);


        //WebClient.UploadValues is equivalent of Http url-encode type post
        client.Method = "POST";
        response = client.UploadString("https://gitlab.mydomain.com/users/auth/ldapmain/callback", postData);
```

Using this class

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public string Method;
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    {
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookies;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0";
            (request as HttpWebRequest).Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            (request as HttpWebRequest).Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            (request as HttpWebRequest).Referer = "https://gitlab.mydomain.com/users/auth/ldapmain/callback";
            (request as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = true;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate |
                                                                 DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            if (Method == "POST")
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            }

        }
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return httpRequest;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        String setCookieHeader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

        if (setCookieHeader != null)
        {
            //do something if needed to parse out the cookie.
            try
            {
                if (setCookieHeader != null)
                {
                    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); //create cookie
                    this.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                    Console.WriteLine(cookie);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        return response;


    }

}
```

The strange thing is that it works sometimes and i can not figure out why it should only work sometimes.

If i try to just keep logging in will i usually get in after 3 times, but sometimes it works 3 times ind a row.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works sometimes"? Does it give an error? Does it reject the token? Something else?

Comment: Sometimes i get logged in other times it just moves me back to the sign in page